# Update array of particular object based on id and Objectid

Tags: node.js, mongodb

> my Database structure

```
_id:ObjectId("123456789")
name:"prudhvi"
authors:Array
0:Object
authorId:123
authorname:"venkat"
department:software
1:Object
authorId:456
authorname:"venkat"
department:hardware
```

My database structure is like this. I need to update `1:Object`, I am trying to update properties based on authorId and also userid(_id)

Can anyone please help. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using mongodb or mongoose?

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried. and are you using mongodb or mongoose?

Comment: I am using mongoose. and I tried this. but it is updating authorId ----->

db.myCollection.update({_id:ObjectId("123456789")},{$set:{"authors":[{authorId:456},{authorname:"dublin"}]}})

Comment: Here i am passing (_id) but i don't know how to pass authorId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this. It is working for me

```
db.myCollection.update({_id:ObjectId("123456789"),authors:{$elemMatch:{authorId:456}}},{$set:{"authors.$.authorname":"prudhvi"}})
```